# Modulo not working on Liquid templates in Logic App, but works locally

Tags: liquid, azure-logic-apps

Following template with any array as content:

```
{%- for datapoint in content -%}
{%- assign breaker = (forloop.index | modulo: 4) -%}
{{breaker}}
{% if breaker == 0 %};
{% endif %}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Produces this output in visual studio code, and is in line with documentation:

```
1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0
```

(I added space instead of new line for readabillity)

Running the same template on azure logic app will produce this output

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Are there any other ways of achieving the same output using Liquid templates, without modulo? Seems like the | might be an issue,

```
{%- assign arraysize = content | size -%}
```

doesnt seem to work either, but

```
{%- assign arraysize = content.size -%}
```

works fine. However I am not sure how to use modulo in this way.

Answer (score 3):

I believe `modulo` should be `Modulo` (the capital 'M')

For Liquid Templates, Logic Apps use the [DotLiquid](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid) library configured with the C# naming convention (refer [this](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/wiki/DotLiquid-for-Designers#filter-and-output-casing)) requiring filter names to be capitalized.

This is also mentioned in a note in the Logic Apps docs for [Transforming JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform#create-liquid-template-or-map-for-your-integration-account).

Basically, the filters will have to be like this compared to the original ruby ones

- `at_least` becomes `AtLeast`
- `plus` becomes `Plus`

**UPDATE:** Not sure if parenthesis are valid in liquid but I had to remove them for Logic Apps

```
{%- for datapoint in content -%}
{%- assign breaker = forloop.index | Modulo: 4 -%}
{{ breaker }}
{%- endfor -%}
```